# how to compute dendrogram for 1 dimensional data set, such as {1,23,45} in R

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I'm not really sure how to represent the 1-D data set properly in R, so that I will be able to plot a dendrogram. 
Please help.

```
##data set {1,23,45}
##this is what I have done so far, but the dendrogram doesn't seem correct.
data <-c(1,23,45)
datas <-data.frame(data)
d<- dist(datas,method="euclidean")
H.fit<- hclust(d,method="single")
plot(H.fit)
```

Answer (score 0):

The plot is correct: every point in your list is being set in the same cluster.

The reason is that you are using single linkage which is the minimum distance between each cluster. In you data, the minimum distance between any pair and the remaining point is the same so everyone gets the same hierarchy.

Try using complete linkage. Your data dimensionality is well represented.